# Java.awt.event classes management

Tags: java, swing

I started writing a game (also taking code parts online) in Java all in one class and now I'm trying to break it into multiple classes but awt.event is giving me problems.
I want the class MainGUI to implement awt.event classes but methods keyPressed and actionPerformed must only contain a call to a method that is in another class that contains the code to be executed in correspondence with the occurrence of the event .

I am doing this because I want the class mainGUI to only realize the game window , leaving the management of controls to another class .

I tried to transfer the code and implement the methods to call and everything works except the method requestFocus .
When I call it indirectly from the class used for the control, asking him to move the focus to the game window, it does not work .

So, the class I want to break is MainGUI and the class I want to manage the controls is Logic:

```
public class MainGUI extends JFrame implements ComponentListener, ActionListener, FocusListener, KeyListener {

//STATIC ATTRIBUTES

private final static int UP = 0, LEFT = 1, DOWN = 2, RIGHT = 3, STOP = 4; 
private final static int NUMBER_OF_ROWS = 70;
private final static int NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS = 70; 
private static int direction; 
private static int currentX, currentY;

//INSTANCE ATTRIBUTES

private BoardPanel drawPanel;
private JPanel bottomPanel;
private JLabel message;
private Timer timer;

//CONSTRUCTOR

public MainGUI() {
   super("Grid");
   createGUI();
}

//PUBLIC INSTANCE METHODS

public void createbottomPanel(){
   this.bottomPanel=new JPanel();
   this.message = new JLabel("To START, Press \"ENTER\"", JLabel.CENTER);
   this.message.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
   this.message.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,0,5,0));
   this.bottomPanel.add(this.message);
}

public void createGUI(){
   this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
   this.drawPanel = new BoardPanel();
   createbottomPanel();

   addComponentListener(this);
   addKeyListener(this);
   addFocusListener(this);
   this.message.addKeyListener(this);

   Container contPane = getContentPane();
   contPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
   contPane.add(this.drawPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
   contPane.add(this.bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

   this.currentX = 50; 
   this.currentY = 30;          
   this.direction = STOP;       
   this.message.requestFocus();

   pack();
}

public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
   this.drawPanel.setGridUnit();
}

public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
   //do-nothing
}

public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
   //do-nothing
 }

public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
    //do-nothing
 }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  switch (direction) {
     case UP:
        if (currentY > 0)
            currentY--;    
        BoardPanel.fillCell(currentX,currentY);
        this.drawPanel.repaint();   
        break;
     case DOWN:
        if (currentY < NUMBER_OF_ROWS-1)
            currentY++;  
        BoardPanel.fillCell(currentX,currentY);
        this.drawPanel.repaint();
        break;
     case RIGHT:
        if (currentX < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS-1)
            currentX++;  
        BoardPanel.fillCell(currentX,currentY);
        this.drawPanel.repaint();
        break;
     case LEFT:
        if (currentX > 0)
            currentX--;  
        BoardPanel.fillCell(currentX,currentY);
        this.drawPanel.repaint();
        break;
  }
}

public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
   direction=STOP;  
   message.setText("To PAUSE, Press \"P\"");
   timer = new Timer(50,this); 
   timer.start();
}

public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
   if (timer != null)
       timer.stop();
   timer = null;
   message.setText("To START, Press \"ENTER\"");
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int code = e.getKeyCode();  

  if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
      direction = LEFT;
  else if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
           direction = RIGHT;
  else if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
           direction = UP;
  else if (code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
           direction = DOWN;
  else if (code == KeyEvent.VK_P)
           message.requestFocus();
  else if (code == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
           this.requestFocus();
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
   //do-nothing    
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
   //do-nothing    
}

//STATIC METHODS

public static void openWindow() {
   javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run () {
                             new MainGUI().setVisible(true);
      }
   });
} 

} // end class
```

The class Logic:

```
public class Logic {

//STATIC ATTRIBUTES

private static MainGUI test = new MainGUI();

//STATIC METHODS   

public static void initGame(){
   test.openWindow();

}
//This method must be called from actionPerformed in MainGUI and 
//contain the code to be executed
public static void logicPerforms(){
  //empty-for-now
}
//This method must be called from keyPressed in MainGUI and 
//contain the code to be executed
public static void logicPress(){
   //empty-for-now
}

} //end-class
```

The classes are in different packages but I omitted the various imports.
The class Boardpanel draws a grid and colors the cell coordinates (x, y) through its method fillCells.
The main class is:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Logic.initGame();

}

} //end-class
```

I transferred the necessary variables in the class Logic, copied the code from the methods actionPerformed and keyPressed of MainGUI and created static methods ( for example, to run the repaint ) to be called from logicPerforms and logicPress to solve call problems but these lines are not working:

```
else if (code == KeyEvent.VK_P)
          test.askMessageFocus();
else if (code == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
          test.askGUIFocus();
```

where askMessageFocus e askGUIFocus are two of those static methods mentioned earlier (they are in the class MainGUI) whose code is:

```
this.message.requestFocus();
```

for askMessageFocus and

```
this.requestFocus();
```

for the other one.

I apologize for my English and other mistakes I may have made ​​in the code, I hope someone can help me!
Almost any advice will be welcome , even aimed at optimizing other parts of code!
Thank you!!

Comment: From the documentation of [`requestFocus()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocus()): "*Note that the use of this method is discouraged because its behavior is platform dependent. Instead we recommend the use of [requestFocusInWindow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocusInWindow()).*"

Comment: It doesn't matter what you want.  Most GUI's are built using the [model / view / controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).  I don't see a game model in your code.  Take a look at my article, [Retro Snake Game](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=768), to see how to use the MVC pattern in Java Swing.

Comment: @VinceEmigh    Yeah I also tried with requestFocusInWindow() but it doesn't work

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc Nice article ,you pause the game with a boolean and manage the keyboard with the binding , I'm thinking of reorganizing my classes similar to yours, so as to better adapt the idea of MVC , my idea was to use a Logic-View. Also I don't need to use requestFocus this way. I'll try!